# Prepared statement keeps false

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm working on a prepared statement that continuously returns false.

```
$db = dblogin();
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `tor_request` `name`,`sdate`,`edate,`reason`,`comment` VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");

echo var_export($stmt,true);
//$stmt->bind_param('siiss',$_POST['name'],$_POST['sdate'],$_POST['edate'],$_POST['reason'],$_POST['comment']);
//$result = $stmt->execute();
```

The dblogin works everywhere, and it has been EXTENSIVELY tested. I just can not find the error in this one statement. It keeps returning false over and over and over. I've commented out the `bind_param` and the `$result` because I can't get past the prepare. It's not an `Object`. Any ideas? Been stuck at this one line for HOURS

Comment: You forgot parenthesis around your INSERT columns, see [MySQL insert syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not wrapping your columns inside brackets, plus you're missing a backtick around `edate`

```
$db = dblogin();
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `tor_request` (`name`,`sdate`,`edate`,`reason`,`comment`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");

echo var_export($stmt,true);
```

Add [error reporting](http://www.php.net/mysqli_error) to the top of your file(s) which will help during production testing.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Error reporting related links:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php
- http://www.php.net/mysqli_error

Comment: The error reporting is what is saving me here! Thank you for that tip!

Comment: You're very much welcome @TechHeadDJ Glad I was of help. It's an indispensible tool.

Answer (score 1):

```
"INSERT INTO `tor_request` (`name`,`sdate`,`edate`,`reason`,`comment`) 
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"
```

PS: Named parameters are so much easier to read. The more text you have THE BETTER.

```
"INSERT INTO `tor_request` (`name`,`sdate`,`edate`,`reason`,`comment`) 
VALUES (:name,:startDate,:endDate,:reason,:comment)"
```

Comment: `[Wed Apr 30 09:54:14 2014] [error]  PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /$`

Edited to remove the comments, still returns false

Comment: You need to practice some basic debugging, make sure your statements actually run in CLI or a tool like phpMyAdmin/SQLYog before using them. These are basic syntax errors.